# Android / Java: Asynchronous job in a loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a method that updates the list of accounts asynchronously in my android app.

The methods looks like this

```
public void updateAccounts(List<String> accountIds, final SampleCallback callback) {
    for (String accountId : accountIds) {
         getAccountsAsync(accountId, new MySampleCallback() {
             @Override public void result(AccountResponse response) {
                 callback(response);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

This is the method that updates the accounts.

```
void getAccountsAsync(String accountId, final MySampleCallback callback) {
     //Execution of request
     callback.result(new AccountsResponse("Just a sample response from the service"));
}
```

and this is my callback interface

```
public interface MySampleCallback{
    void result(AccountsResponse response);
}
```

The problem is, in my execution of the loop, I only get the result of the last item of the list e.g
I have a list of String -> "One", "Two", "Three"

The only result that I get is the one from the last item which is three.

The other two are being ignored, however they are still being executed but the only result that returns to me is the last item.

What I'm trying to do is, before the loop's next iteration, can I stop it before executing the next one? More like running making this Async run Synchronously.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you could really use RxJava to (possibly) simplify this

Comment: @cricket_007 RxJava has nothing to do with this - don't go suggesting a huge hammer when a small one suffices.

Comment: I'm gonna check it out, but could site a specific example using RxJava for my use case? thanks man!

Comment: @Aaron Are you sure you posted the exact code you're running? Since from what it looks, it shouldn't compile (e.g. missing `final` for `SampleCallback` parameter).

Comment: If getAccountsAsync method is an AsyncTask then you are doing a mistake. You need to look for alternative. The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

Comment: Check again console log
updateAccounts(array, response -> System.out.println(response));

public void updateAccounts(List<String> accountIds,final MySampleCallback callback) {
        for (String accountId : accountIds) {
           getAccountsAsync(accountId, response -> callback.result(response));
        }
    }

void getAccountsAsync(String accountId, MySampleCallback callback) {
callback.result(new AccountsResponse("Just a sample response from the service"+accountId));
    }
got 3 outputs
service one
service two
service three

Comment: @manabreak just updated the post, sorry I posted an example code snippet like my code.

Comment: try this `for (final String accountId : accountIds) {`

Comment: @manabreak I agree it's a large hammer but both the requests to "loop over" (or map) ID elements to perform async requests, then "subscribe" to "one to many" responses seems like a good use case for that library.

Comment: would it be possible if I get to wait for the response first, before the next iteration? Sort of like making it synchronous

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to solve this the wrong way.  You need to make an async call on N items.  Instead of making N calls, write a single call that takes an array of ids on the server.

Comment: Apparently I would't be able to do that, because the task that I'm calling is a web scraping service. Inside the getAccountAsync, I'm loading a webview for web scraping, thus making me wait for the response. Once the response arrives, I only get to access the last item of the list.

Comment: WHy would you load a webview to scrape rather than make a direct HTTP call?  That makes no sense, and sounds like the cause of your issues.  There is 0 reason to involve a graphical element there.